# A-frame laser pointer wrong angle

Tags: aframe

I've just added the laser pointer to the right hand in my A-Frame scene and it's pointing in the wrong direction.

[A-frame Laser pointing 45deg to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5PVh.jpg)

In this image I am pointing at the blue box above the tower using an Oculus Touch controller. As you can see the hand is pointing correctly and feels like it matches my real life hand position quite well but the laser is going about 45deg to the left.

Here is my code:

```
<a-entity id="cameraRig" position="-25 -10 138" rotation="0 -25 0">
<a-entity id="head" camera="near: 0.1; far: 10000" wasd-controls look-controls></a-entity>
<a-entity id="teleHand" hand-controls="left" teleport-controls="cameraRig: #cameraRig; teleportOrigin: #head; type: parabolic; button: trigger; collisionEntities: #terrain, #bridgeFull"></a-entity>
<a-entity id="pointerHand" hand-controls="right" laser-controls></a-entity>
```

Is there a way I can reposition the laser? Ideally to come out of the pointing fingure but if not then just pointing in the right direction will do?

Update: I just tried `raycaster="showLine: true"` instead and this does point in the correct direction so it appears to be a bug with the laser component. I could use the raycaster and write my own collision logic but would much prefer to use the mouse events that you get with the laser.

Second Update: Just discovered if I add both the raycaster and cursor component I get the exact same functionality as adding the laser component but with the raycast pointing in the correct direction.

This has solved the problem I have but will leave this here as I'm sure others will run into this problem until the laser component is fixed.

I've filed an issue here https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3396

For clarity I was using v0.7.1 of A-frame

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so to post the answer here. `hand-controls` and `laser-controls` aren't meant to mix. Hand controls is more for 6DoF and laser-controls is more if you want to support both 3DoF and 6DoF. Laser-controls will set its own raycaster properties on `controllerconnected` event.

To set your own raycaster properties:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('force-raycaster', {
  schema: {
    direction: {type: 'vec3'},
    origin: {type: 'vec3'}
  },

  init: function () {
    this.el.addEventListener('controllerconnected', {
      // Wait for laser-controls to set its raycaster properties.
      setTimeout(() { 
        this.el.setAttribute('raycaster', this.data);
      }, 50);
    });
  }
});

<a-entity laser-controls hand-controls force-raycaster="direction: 0 0 -1; origin: 0 -0.1 0">
```